# Rename Columns in Pandas Using Lambda Function Rather Than a Function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to rename column headings in my dataframe in pandas using `.rename()`.

Basically, the headings are :

```
column 1: "Country name[9]"
column 2: "Official state name[5]"

#etc.
```

I need to remove `[number]`.

I can do that with a function:

```
def column(string):
    for x, v in enumerate(string):
        if v == '[':
           return string[:x]
```

But I wanted to know how to convert this to a `lambda` function so that I can use

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x: do same as function)
```

I've never used `lambda` functions before so I'm not sure of the syntax to get it to work correctly.

Comment: `df.columns.str.replace(r'\[\d+\]$', '')`?....Details about [`regex pattern`](https://regex101.com/r/5NafeZ/1/)

Comment: I ended up using the function: df.rename(columns = lambda p: column(p), inplace = True) which works well. The stripping function doesn't seem to work for some reason - maybe because it has multiple headings.

Comment: you can use your function in `lambda x: column(x)` or you would first create function which return some value in `else:`

Comment: BTW: instead of `df.rename(columns=lambda p: column(p), inplace=True)` you can write `df.rename(columns=column, inplace=True)` because `columns=` expects function which gets one argument and your function gets one argument.

Answer (score 1):

First you would have to create function which returns new or old value - never `None`.

```
def column(name):
    if '[' in name:
        return name[:name.index('[')]  # new - with change
    else:
        return name  # old - without change
```

and then you can use it as

```
df.rename(columns=lambda name:columns(name))
```

or even simpler

```
df.rename(columns=columns)
```

Or you can convert your function to real `lambda`

```
df.rename(columns=(lambda name: name[:name.index('[')] if '[' in name else name) )
```

but sometimes it is more readable to keep `def column(name)` and use `columns=column`. And not all constructions can be used in `lambda` - ie. you can't assing value to variable (I don't know if you can use new operator `:=` ("walrus") in Python 3.8).

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Country name[9]': [1,2,3],
    'Official state name[5]': [4,5,6],
    'Other': [7,8,9],
}    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def column(name):
    if '[' in name:
        return name[:name.index('[')]
    else:
        return name

print(df.columns)

df = df.rename(columns=column)        

# or 

df = df.rename(columns=(lambda name: name[:name.index('[')] if '[' in name else name) )

print(df.columns)
```